# reader mode on iOS Chrome?

Tags: ios, software-recommendation, google-chrome, web-browser

I miss Safari’s Reader mode’s ability to cut down on website cruft, for example Medium’s banners.

But I really don’t like Safari otherwise.

Can I get Reader mode in Chrome?  How? I tried **chrome://flags/** but no luck.

getting **Open in Safari** option in Chrome’s Share menu would be OK as a workaround.  Right now it’s copy url, open Safari, paste url.

Firefox is my main desktop browser but not interested in it on iOS. I’d prefer Chrome be extended to perform this function, but I’m open to any and all third party browsers that can emulate the Safari reader mode function.

Answer (score 3):

Someone suggested I use `Workflow` to address another question I had.

And it occurred to me that I could use it here as well (you'll need to be at least on iOS 11.x - Workflow is much, much, less powerful on 10.x.

You need to create an `Action Extension` workflow, set it up to `only accept URLs` and then choose `Open in Safari` as an action.

You may also need to enable Workflow in sharing.

#### configuration screenshots

Here's a **rough** series of screenshots, from when you've launched Workflow.  Sorry, it's a little bit complicated and fully detailing each step in the series would take a lot of little dialog screenshots, but hopefully you'll get the idea.

Also, keep in mind iOS 12 is apparently replacing Workflow with `Shortcuts` so there might be another way to do this later.

#### Final result:

The upshot is that I can pick `Workflow` in Sharing, then my Workflow, which I've saved to `Safari`.

[image]

#### Update:

confusingly it seems as if `Shortcuts` is only a rebranding of `Workflow`, so my instructions apply to it as well.

Last, you `Firefox Focus` has an `open in Safari` option.

Comment: This answer may be outdated, or it may need to be corrected. As of iOS 12, the Workflow app has been superseded by the new Shortcuts app. This app contains a shortcut in its gallery named Open Safari Reader that should achieve  the goal in the original question. The shortcut is also available here; https://www.icloud.com/shortcuts/690b04935e5849329eabff8c7bcd90a2

Answer (score 2):

This is actually even easier now. In fact, the new Shortcuts Gallery has an Open Safari Reader shortcut that you can use out of the box. It is pretty slick.

Thanks so much for asking this question, I’ve been looking for this ever since Safari Reader View came out.

I just wish the individual Shortcut itself could be one of the Sharing widgets rather than the extra step of clicking Shortcuts and then the Open Safari Reader icon. I thought having a Siri phrase might help but it doesn’t seem to pass the URL. When I am viewing a webpage in Chrome and use Siri to run the shortcut it just goes to the Shortcuts app but doesn’t successfully hand off the URL.